# How do I randomly generate a grid style island map, given two tile types?

Tags: c++

I need to write an algorithm than can assign a tile type (one for water and one for land) to every square in a 100 x 100 grid, and I would like it to generate an "island". Something random, but all the land squares together, and all the water squares on the border. Any ideas?

I have heard of "perlin noise" but I don't know how to implement it to give the result I want. I feel like also my case is probably too basic for such a complicated algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: First idea it comes into my mind, just made it up, is a two step process: first you start always from a given position (e.g. center or a random picked one), and then move randomly for that one producing a random path on the map, then you make the path "bold" enough to make a island without "lakes" (if you need it). This is just an idea to start with... If you don't find anything better, I can elaborate on that and try to make a working algorithm.

Comment: Another idea is to randomly create connected shapes... For example, you start from a rectangle in the center, then create a random rectangle that is on its perimeter, and go on, randomly choosing, almost-randomly stopping.

Comment: Fractal terrain with a high starting point in the middle will be island-like.

Comment: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/

Answer (score 3):

A roguelike I play, called Brogue, uses a cellular automata rule to generate lakes and caves, and such a rule could be applied to make islands instead, as they are generated in a satisfyingly blobby fashion that looks congealed but not overly circular/square.

Read about it here: http://brogue.wikia.com/wiki/Level_Generation#Lakes

Sample:

*A buffer as big as the level is used, and seeded with 55% alive elements and 45% dead elements. 5 iterations are made of the rule B5678/S45678:*

*If I am dead and have 5-8 alive neighbours, I become alive.*

*If I am alive and have 4-8 alive neighbours, I stay alive, else I become dead.*

*After this, every 'blob' of horizontally/vertically connected alive elements is counted, and the largest blob smaller than lakeMaxWidth and lakeMaxHeight is preserved. If no blob is made larger than 4x4 and smaller than this, the cellular automata is started over.*

Comment: Using this algorithm, but trimming the edges, you get this after one iteration: https://i.imgur.com/O7fAnaX.png (32x32).  I found that it stabilizes around 14 iterations: https://i.imgur.com/omlYv4d.png

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the width of your map `w`, the height `h` and the center point `C`. `C` is a 2 dimensional vector `(w / 2, h / 2)`.

As you get farther away from `C`, the probability of water should increase, preferably with some kind of cut-off point.

Let's call the point currently being evaluated `P`, it too is a 2 dimensional vector `(x, y)` where `x` and `y` is the coordinates.

`P - C = D` gives us a new vector `D`, the length of which is the distance from the center to the point being evaluated.

As a first implementation, let's say that when the length (or magnitude) of `D` is larger than `w - 20` we put a water tile down.

Now we build our grid. Iterate over every tile, and calculate `D`. `if D > (w - 20)`, we mark the tile as water, otherwise we mark it as land.

This gives us a "perfectly" circular island.

---

Let's introduce some randomness. We modify our condition to `if D > ((w - 20) + randint(4))` (where `randint(x)` returns a random integer, from 0 up to x). Now we get some kind of scragged coast line.

It is possible that we get small isolated land tiles with this condition. It can be solved but not with such an easy condition, [Thomas Matthews ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15213822/12183) would work better in this case.

The island will still be rather circular, but how scragged it is depends on what you feed `randint` in the condition. If `randint(someval)` yields a value larger than 20, we might not get any water at all at the border, so look out for such scenarios.

---

If we instead want some kind of square island, we will need to check our distance from the borders instead. It is easy too, for example to see if we are within 4 tiles of the left border: `P.x < 5` or within 10 tiles from the right border `P.x > w - 5`.

---

About perlin noise, and a shameless plug. I am working, in my spare time, on a library that generates lattice noise (Perlin is a kind of lattice noise.) You can use the code freely for whatever you wish or just look at it if you want too [here](https://github.com/skurmedel/latticenoise/tree/master/src). It is by no means complete, and I'm sure there are bugs in there, but it can generate fractal noise.

Perlin noise has many desirably properties, but may require some additional processing (usually simple math) to shape it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting the grid to all water.  On Earth, there is more water than land mass.

Next, pick a random point.  Assign it as land.
For each side of your new island, you could generate a random number to determine the next square relative to the first, where land will be.  You may also add some weights and rules so that you don't get 'lakes' on your island and that land touches land.

Search the web for "terrain editor".  The Sim City games had some terrain editors that also allowed depth from mountains to lakes.

Comment: The algorithm for *Conway's Game of Life* keeps popping into my head.  Instead of having two "families", you have land versus ocean.

Comment: A fractal (algorithm) pattern could be used also.  Splash in a little Fibonacci algorithm too.